# Is it possible to upgrade from RHEL 4 to 6 with up2date(or yum) on or after 2012/08?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

I'd like to upgrade my server's os from RHEL 4 to 6 after 2012/08.

I know that there are 2 methods to upgrade.

```
1. directly (RHEL 4 -> 6):
  1. buy a new server machine.
  2. install RHEL6 on the machine.
  3. move my system from old machine to new machine.
  4. swap these machines.

2. one by one (RHEL 4 -> 5 -> 6):
  1. upgrade from RHEL 4 to RHEL 5 with up2date command.
  2. upgrade from RHEL 5 to RHEL 6 with yum command.
```

I'd like to use 2nd method.
However, I heard that Redhat was already stopped the support of REHL4 since 2012/03.

Is it possible to upgrade from RHEL 4 to 6 with up2date(or yum) on or after 2012/08?

Answer (score 1):

Redhat has stopped mainstream support of RHEL 4, but that doesn't mean that they wiped the package repositories.

I have no idea, though, how one would use up2date to go from RHEL 4 to RHEL 5. I don't even think RedHat supports such upgrade paths. They are, in essence, hacks, AFAIK. You can do it manually, and always remember to upgrade to x.oldest to (x+1).0 and only then update to (x+1).oldest. So when going from 4 to 6 using any route, you will go as follows:

- update to 4.9
- upgrade to 5.0
- update to 5.8
- upgrade to 6.0
- update to 6.2

Comment: Thanks for answer!

My team mate was told me that a similar question has already exists.

  http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/rhel6/rhel_6_installation/rhel_6_installation_ch-upgrade-x86.html

As you say, RedHat don't seem to support support mejure version up with up2date.
So, i may have to do any one of the following two methods.
  1) buy a new server machine and install most recent RHEL.
  2) crean install of a new RHEL on same machine.
thanks :D

Comment: I seriously suggest getting a new machine. It seems that anything over 5 years old is not energy efficient, and usually much louder as well. At least I find it so with dell servers. Their 2600 and 2800 were monsters compared with modern offerings.